# Regular Expression for splitting string by number of characters

Tags: c#

I have a 2D Barcode that I need to be parsed into two different items. I want my first expression to read the first 10 characters (numbers and letters) only. The second expression I want the first 10 characters to be ignored and then read the remaining characters (numbers, letters, _ ). The total number of characters remaing are not consistant.

Here is a sample of what the barcode reads. 20P0000002_0_DP-3_TR_DEBIT

Any suggestions?

Comment: First question, 0 effort. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 10):

You don't need regular expressions, [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) will do:

```
var first = barcode.Substring(0, 10);
var second = barcode.Substring(10);
```

You can then check if the first part is just letters and numbers with the nice but not theoretically 100% accurate

```
var isValid = first.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

or with the more prosaic

```
var acceptable = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
var isValid = first.All(c => acceptable.IndexOf(c.ToUpper()) != -1);
```

Comment: The problem I see with that is - there's no validation going on. This might sometimes be required.

Comment: @ananthonline: True, I missed that part. Since the other answers give regex-based solutions I added non-regex-based approaches here. Incidentally, your regex is more loose than it should be (it's the equivalent of checking with `char.IsLetterOrDigit`, and it also allows underscores).

Comment: I thought the OP wanted underscores as well. :) Edited.

Answer (score 2):

For your first expression you would use this.

```
^([\dA-Za-z]{10})
```

- `^` = match beginning of string
- `(` = begin capture group
- `[` = begin set of characters to match
- `\d` = match all digits (0-9)
- `A-Za-z` = match all uppercase and lowercase letters
- `]` = end character set
- `{10}` = match exactly 10 of the previous character set
- `)` = end capture group

For your second, this one

```
^.{10}(.*)$
```

- `^.{10} = match the first ten characters of the string (but don't capture them)
- `(.*)$ = capture all remaining characters until the end of the string

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, you could easily combine these two expressions into one like so.

```
^([\dA-Za-z]{10})(.*)$
```

This will yield two capture groups with only one match operation.

It's worth noting that using a RegEx might be a good solution since the match will tell you whether or not the initial ten characters are only alphanumeric characters. If you're only seeking to capture the first ten characters regardless of what they are, then a RegEx is overkill. But if you want validation, a RegEx is a nice way to do that. Performance could be argued though, but you're already using .NET which carries some performance impact anyway.

Comment: This is the only regex-based solution that accurately nails down the validation restrictions (at least as of now), but why split the regex in two parts?

Comment: @Jon - since the original post asked for two, I worked to meet those requirements. I agree with you, if you don't need to evaluate the RegEx's at two different times, they can be combined into one. I'll update my answer to reflect this option. Thanks!

Comment: I am having problems getting the second string to work. When I test it is matching but is bringing in the entire string. I need it to drop the first 10 characters.

Comment: You might be looking at the first group, which will be the matched string. You want to use the second group, which will be the first capture group. `var objRegex= new Regex("^.{10}(.*)$"); var objMatch=objRegex.Match("20P0000002_0_DP-3_TR_DEBIT"); Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[1].ToString());`